# Download not working for bash scripts in browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I require to download a content which start with value of variable result. The downloaded page appears empty which i feel is a problem with encoding. Could you please help rectifying this?

This is being done on client-end and I have no control over backend so this is the only approach feasible.

```js
   var result="#!/usr/bin/env bash";
  const filenamecc ="result";
   const url = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(result);
   const link = document.createElement("a");
   link.setAttribute("href", url);
   link.setAttribute("download", filenamecc + ".sh");
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

`#` is a special character in URLs (and your data starts with it). Use Base64 encoding.

And get the content-type right.

```
const buff = new Buffer(result);
const encoded = buff.toString('base64');
const uri = 'data:text/x-shellscript;charset=utf-8;base64,' + encoded;
```

Answer (score 0):

The encodeURIComponent function should be used to encode queryString parameters, in particular URLs and any Special Characters present in query string .

The difference between **encodeURI** and **encodeURIComponent** is **encodeURIComponent** encodes the entire string, where encodeURI ignores protocol prefix

Replace **encodeURI** with **encodeURIComponent**

```js
   var result="#!/usr/bin/env bash";
   const filenamecc ="result";
   const url = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(result);
   const link = document.createElement("a");
   link.setAttribute("href", url);
   link.setAttribute("download", filenamecc + ".sh");
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)